# AEM form data submission using ajax

Tags: ajax, forms, aem

I want to submit data from an angular app to aem, using aem form. Is there a way of calling the submit form action of the aem form using ajax?

Comment: You can use $http in angularjs https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post or if you have access to jquery, just use jquery ajax https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: As mentioned above, you can simply send your POST request to the servlet that handles the submissions by using Angular (I assume AngularJS?) simply doing something like so:

<form ng-submit="submit()" id="form-id" name="form-name">
...
</form>


And then in your form controller handle the submission with the $http object:

$scope.submit = function() {
    var postUrl = '/bin/join';
    $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/bin/yourservlet',
      data: yourFormModel,
      headers: { ...  }
    }).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
  };